# How do I work with zend_pdf in magento?

Tags: magento

How do I create a PDF in Magento and write something on it? Here is the sample piece that I have been playing with "on a blank page".

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

require_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/app/Mage.php');
Mage::app();

/* --------------------------------------------------------- */

$pdf = new Zend_Pdf('w2.pdf'); 

$pdf->drawText('sample text', 420,628);

// instruct browser to download the PDF
header("Content-Type: application/x-pdf");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=w2.pdf");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");

// output the PDF
echo $pdf->save('w3.pdf');
```

But this is the error I'm receiving.

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Pdf_Exception' with message 'File is not a PDF.' in /Volumes/www/vhosts/magento/lib/Zend/Pdf/Parser.php:396 Stack trace: #0 /Volumes/www/vhosts/magento/lib/Zend/Pdf.php(309): Zend_Pdf_Parser->__construct('w2.pdf', Object(Zend_Pdf_ElementFactory_Proxy), false) #1 /Volumes/www/vhosts/magento/scripts/pdf_gen.php(10): Zend_Pdf->__construct('w2.pdf') #2 {main} thrown in /Volumes/www/vhosts/magento/lib/Zend/Pdf/Parser.php on line 396
```

The Error doesn't make sense because the w2.pdf is an actual pdf located in the same directory. The w3.pdf file doesnt exist, would this be the problem? Also i changed

```
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf('w2.pdf');
to
$pdf = new Zend_Pdf();
```

and received this error

```
Fatal error: Call to undefined method Zend_Pdf::drawText()
```

I also tried renaming the w2.pdf to another pdf that i downloaded from the internet including the $pdf->save('file_i_downloaded) and i still get the File is not a PDF error.

This is the PDF I am using: http://www.getharvest.com/resources/invoice-template-pdf

Answer (score -2):

This service here allows you to easily edit your PDF documents.
http://goo.gl/MEA3jT

You can fill out PDF form, save it, fax it, and email it.